# cannot get css sprite working with background-repeat

Tags: css, sprite, css-sprites

I try to get css sprite working on my page. but if I adds background-repeat:no-repeat. then the css sprite stops working.  If I remove it from my stylesheet, will work again.

I couldn't figure out why I cannot use background-repeat.

here's my code.  I also upload it to jsfiddle, you can test it there.

http://jsfiddle.net/F49b5/2/

```
        <html>
        <head>
            <style type="text/css">
                #logo a, .vote-up-off, .vote-up-on, .vote-down-off, .vote-down-on, .star-on
                {
                    background-image: url("http://i14.photobucket.com/albums/a332/007bond-jb/food/burger2.jpg");
                    overflow: hidden;
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;  /*this is the problem, remove it, it will work */
                }
                #logo a, .vote-up-off, .vote-up-on, .vote-down-off, .vote-down-on, .star-on, .star-off, .flag-off, .vote-accepted-off, .vote-accepted-on
                {
                    font-size: 1px;
                    text-indent: -9999em;
                }

                #logo a
                {
                    background-position: 0 194px;
                    width: 309px;
                    height: 133px;
                    display: block;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="logo">
                <a href="/" title="test">test</a>
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Can you post this in a fiddle and hyperlink to your sprite? It's really hard to see what's going on as I'm not seeing a background position on more than one of your elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try switching your background-position to -194px instead of 194px:

```
#logo a
{
    background-position: 0 -194px;
    width: 309px;
    height: 133px;
    display: block;
}
```

By setting the y-axis to 194px, it will push the background image down 194px, which is out of the view of your #logo height. Instead, you'll want to "pull up" the image by setting the y-axis to a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the background position outside of the height of the box.

Repeat repeats the whole image from 0:0 of the element which is why you see it.

Remove your background position and it will work.